# Should I use "I" or "We" in Peer-Review Journal Submissions?

Tags: publications, writing-style

I am the single author for a journal article which focuses on the measurement and validation of two scale instruments. This is a purely quantitative report for submission in a top-tier educational psychology journal. Where appropriate, I have used the plural first-person "we" in the article, as "I" sounds very peculiar to me. I also feel as though it is disadvantageous to write singular first-person when submitting for blind peer-review. At the same time, I don't want readers thinking I have multiple personality disorder as more than one person. ;)

In your opinion, should I be using "I" or "We?"

FYI I'd rather not use passive voice. It's madness for this article.

Thanks for your thoughts in advance.

Comment: What do similar papers in your field do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the conventions in your field. I suspect that in most fields papers use 'we' since most papers are authored by more than one person. I would personally use 'we'.